# Hiding vertical scrollbar in google sites embeded code is not working on android

Tags: google-sites

I am trying to embed code in google sites, without the extra vertical scrollbar. While the code below is giving the desired result in computer, it is not working on mobile/tab (in preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Trial</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].scrolling="no"; </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style> ul#menu li {display:inline;} </style>
    <style>
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family:Roboto Light;;font-size: 16px">
    <p style="font-family:Roboto Light;;font-size: 16px">Our group has two broad research area with
    a single goal
    </p>
    <h1 style="font-family:Roboto Light; color:#990000">Embeded Design</h1>
    <p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec. Tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet. Dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque. Vulputate odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat. Mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan. Nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum.

Velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec. Amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. Dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in. Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed.
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how to do that?